# Tycho Maven: Adding a local repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, tycho

I have a plug-in project with several dependencies. Among them, there are a couple that are NOT in the official p2 Eclipse repository. They have been installed manually from its "private" update site.

Tycho can not compile the plug-in since it cannot find out where the local dependency is.

`[ERROR]   Missing requirement: es.uma.lcc.e-motions 2.0.1.qualifier requires 'bundle es.upv.dsic.issi.moment.mdt.maudedaemon 1.3.6' but it could not be found`

These dependencies are jars in the `eclipse/plugins` folder. Can I add this folder as repository to my generated pom.xml?